Can I create a mock response in a Guzzle middleware?
I'm writing a PHPUnit test in Drupal and I want to mock the response that the SUT will receive when it makes HTTP calls.
For example, the SUT will make a request to 'http://example.com/some-resource' and I want the test to supply mocked data for that.
I can figure out how to get my own client middleware into the stack, but in the docs at https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html I can't see an example where middleware returns a response, only code that modifies one.
I've poked around in Drupal's HTTP client code, and in ClientFactory it passes a handler stack and relies on GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack's default handler logic.
Can client middleware return a response and bypass the rest of the stack and the handler?

I'm not familiar with Drupal, but the right way would be using Guzzle's own MockHandler, so maybe try exploring that route and see if it fits your expectations (see docs).
Basically, you would set up a mock handler, and supply it with your fake response(s). Then, pass the handler stack with that mock to the client upon instantiating it. Something like this:
$mockHandler = new MockHandler();
$mockHandler->append(
    new Response(200, ['some_header' => 'value'], '{"your_mocked_response": "something"}')
);

$client = new Client(['handler' => HandlerStack::create($mockHandler)]);

$response = $client->request("GET", "/something"); // mocked response will be returned

